# Getting all the values (checked and unchecked) from the dynamic checkbox in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm adding a textbox and a corresponding checkbox to the view on click of a button. These checkbox will determine if the textbox value needs to be shown or hidden.

With the below code I've getting all the textbox fields, but for the checkbox I only get the checked values.

This is the view part

```
 $('#btn-Add-Key-Name').click(function (e) {
       i++;
            e.preventDefault();
                $(`<div class="row" id="rowid`+ i +`">
                        <div class= "col col-4" >
                            <section>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-id-badge"></i>
                                    <input type="text" name="KeyName" value="" placeholder="Key Name">
                                </label>
                            </section>
                        </div>                       
                        <div class="col col-2">
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="IsKeyValid" value="true">
                                <i></i> Key
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div >`).appendTo($fields);
            });

On the Controller

    public JsonResult AddKeyToDB(string[] KeyName, IEnumerable<string> IsKeyValid)
    {
    }
```

//Is there a way to get the unchecked values as well for eg:

```
keyName = ["private", "public"] ,
IsKeyValid = ["false", "true"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html you dont need to hard-code value of checkbox thats why you are only having checked values. So you need to make following change to your code. Just remove value="true" from input type checkbox.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="IsKeyValid" >
```